# How can I fix this function without using any modulo operators?

Tags: python, iteration, boolean-operations

I've currently written a function that takes odd numbers as true and even numbers as false without the use of the modulo operator. When I pass the function into a code processor I get the error: **AssertionError: True is not false : should return False when a number is even**. I do not understand this because the code works when I plug just about any odd or even value (regardless of sign) into my IDE. Here is the code:

```
def is_odd_without_modulo(num):
    if num > 0:
        while num > 0: 
            num -= 2 
            if num == 0: 
                return False
    elif num < 0: 
        while num < 0: 
            num += 2 
            if num == 0:
                return False
    return True
```

Comment: what if `num==0`?

Comment: Just a side note... if it's just to avoid modulo because the code processor looks for it and throws it out... you might just be able to make your function `return bool(num & 1)`

Comment: That was in fact the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to check if a number is even or odd:

For example:

```
# look at last bit
def is_odd_without_modulo(num): return num&1 == 1

# use an integer division (variant 1)
def is_odd_without_modulo(num): return num//2 != (num+1)//2

# use an integer division (variant 2)
def is_odd_without_modulo(num): return num//2*2 != num

# use an integer division (variant 3)
def is_odd_without_modulo(num): return num//2*2 - num < 0

# a recursive variant of your -2 approach
def is_odd_without_modulo(num):
    if num > 1  : return is_odd_without_modulo(num-2)
    if num < -1 : return is_odd_without_modulo(num+2)
    return num != 0

# or an iterative variant of it
def is_odd_without_modulo(num):
    if num < 0 : num = -num
    while num>1: num -= 2
    return num == 1

# an unconventional solution using strings
def is_odd_without_modulo(num): return str(num)[-1] in "13579"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, you maybe missing an else loop structure. Other thing, would be how is the input being taken care off, when you execute this function, like built-in hard-coded values or a user input etc...

And when you do enter an odd number like 5, maybe consider adding an else statement after the inner if statements in both cases as that would return True for an odd number. Then you can remove the line:

```
   return True
```

at the end.

Hope that helps.

Comment: `else` is not a loop

Comment: else can be part of a loop structure, but depends on how it's perceived, most cases it's considered a "loop keyword".

Comment: That is not correct at all. `else` is not a "loop keyword".

Comment: No it is never considered a loop keyword. `for` and `while` are loops. Also a list can be part of a loop, that doesn't make it a "loop keyword"